# Edema and hydrostatic pressure

Tags: cell-biology, pathology, hematology, medicine, blood-pressure

I'm currently studying Robbins basic pathology, and I'm confused about a specific statement:

It states in the book that when hydrostatic pressure is low due to a lack of albumin synthesis, it leads to a net movement of fluid into the interstitial spaces.

However to me that doesn't make any sense: isn't the hydrostatic pressure the thing that facilitates the net movement of particles across the capillaries, **so if there is a lack of it, shouldn't the particles not move across the membrane?**

Any help appreciated

Comment: Citing the edition, chapter and page number, plus the context in which the statement is made in the book, would be helpful.

Comment: it was chapter 4, page 80-81

Comment: You might consider cross-posting this to StackExchange Medical Sciences, as human physiology is more of a focus there.